# Media control of websites on windows 10?

Tags: windows, music, hardware

One of my favorite Mac programs is [BeardedSpice](https://github.com/beardedspice/beardedspice), which (per its github page) "allows you to control web based media players (Like SoundCloud and YouTube) and some native apps with the media keys found on Mac keyboards."

My windows 10 computer has media keys that seem to be well integrated with the OS and other programs (they use the `Fn` key/lock), but they don't let me control website content. I'm looking for a windows 10 equivalent of BeardedSpice that:

- Lets me control website media content (e.g. YouTube and SoundCloud) with my media keys
- doesn't need the website to be the active window

Ideally, this program also:

- works with firefox
- supports using media control buttons from my bluetooth speaker
- is FOSS